# Windows 10 - How to delete temp files for network computer for each users profile

Tags: command-line, windows-7, windows-10, temporary-files

Hi I am trying to create a .bat script which deletes all the temp files in each user's profile and other temp folders

All of the computers (Windows 7, Windows 10) are networked.

Here is what I have done so far

```
set /P remotepc="What is the Remote PC Name? "
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Temp /S /Q /F
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Temp /S /Q /A:H
FOR /D %%p IN (\\"%remotepc%\c$\Temp\*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Windows\Temp /S /Q /F
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Windows\Temp /S /Q /A:H
FOR /D %%p IN ("\\%remotepc%\c$\Windows\Temp\*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Windows\Prefetch /S /Q /F
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Windows\Prefetch /S /Q /A:H
FOR /D %%p IN ("\\%remotepc%\c$\Windows\Prefetch\*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp /S /Q /F
del \\%remotepc%\c$\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp /S /Q /A:H
FOR /D %%p IN ("\\%remotepc%\c$\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
timeout /t 30 /nobreak  
pause
```

In the last section %USERNAME% field only picks up the user currently logged into local machine from where the command is run.
example on Computer "Main" user is "Bravo", when I run the bat file it does this:

```
C:\Users\bravo\Desktop>del \\network-pc\c$\Users\bravo\AppData\Local\Temp /S /Q /F
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\sasar\Desktop>del \\network-pc\c$\Users\bravo\AppData\Local\Temp /S /Q /A:H
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

It runs the first three set of commands on the remote PC and clears off the Temp and Prefetch folder

My main concern is what command do I use in which I should be able to run this command from my computer which deletes all the temp files and skips any file that is in use for all the users on that networked PC.

This will save loads of time regarding doing a cleanup on each users profile one by one.

**If there is a way in PowerShell please let me know how to in PS Script.**